# How do I switch bros?

Tags: broforce, the-expendabros

So I'm happily playing along with my favourite bro, when I happen upon another bro to be freed.

I want to complete my mission, so I free him, but now I switch automatically to him as well. But he's totally lame, I want my old bro back!

How do I do that? How do I switch between bros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't switch between bros, only way to return to your previous bro is killing yourself (your in-game bro, not yourself in real life).